# What did Seppala think was the matter with Togo's paw?

Tags: plot-explanation, togo

Towards the end of the film *Togo*, the titular dog has a bandaged paw and limps. But discussing his survival, Seppala is dismissive of his wife's comment about the paw, and says "You've seen it before", and implies... Something. But what was he alluding to, or saying he thought?